# Why is the Feynman propagator $\langle 0|T \phi(x) \phi^\dagger(y) |0 \rangle$ instead of $\langle 0 |T \phi^\dagger(x) \phi(y) |0 \rangle$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, antimatter, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

If we expand a complex scalar field in terms of Fourier components, we can see that $\langle 0 |T \phi^\dagger(x) \phi(y) |0 \rangle$ contains terms which are not contained in $\langle 0|T \phi(x) \phi^\dagger(y) |0 \rangle$. (Roughly, $\langle 0 | \phi^\dagger(x) \phi(y) |0 \rangle$ describe antiparticle creation and then annihilation, while $\langle 0 | \phi(x) \phi^\dagger(y) |0 \rangle$ describes particle creation and then annihilation.)

Thus I would suspect that the "full" Feynman propagator is a sum of these two terms. However, in textbooks it is standard to define the propagator as
$$ \Delta_F( x-y) \equiv \langle 0|T \phi(x) \phi^\dagger(y) |0 \rangle .$$

Why does this definition make sense and, in particular, why don't we use $\langle 0|T \phi^\dagger(x) \phi(y) |0 \rangle$ instead?

Comment: Sufficient *for what*? What do you think it could be insufficient for? You say that you suspect the "full" Feynman propagator should be a sum of terms for particle and anti-particle creation, but it's not clear to me why you think that, or what your (apparently non-standard) definition of "full Feynman propagator" is.

Comment: @ACuriousMind At page 114 in Tong's notes http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf he writes down the two terms I consider here for a fermion field explicitly (Eq. 5.33). On the next page he then defines the Feynman propagator using only one of these terms. I'm trying to understand why this definition makes sense. In other words, why don't we define the Feynman propagator using the second term or a sum of the two terms?